# Uploading the app to AppStore when DataBase(Coredata) is changed(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, app-store

I would like to know details about how to re-upload the application to AppStore when there is change in the Database(Coredata) fields. Because when i rebuild the app after Database changes there will be crash ,So to avoid the crash i have to reinstall the application.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Check a new field in your database 
Step 2 : Using alter query add that column in your database

Try below code and apply your suitable logic. After this feedback me.
Happy to help you :)

```
+(void)alterCountryexitcodeTable{

    BOOL isAlterRequired = [self checkColumnExists];

    if (!isAlterRequired) {
        sqlite3 *database;
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_open([kDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE countries ADD COLUMN countryexitcode TEXT"];
            const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

            if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
//                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB altered" message:@"Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//                [alert show];
//                alert=nil;
            }
            else
            {
//                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB Updation" message:@"DB not Altered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//                [alert show];
//                alert=nil;
            }
            // Release the compiled statement from memory
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);    
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
}

+(BOOL)checkColumnExists
{
    BOOL columnExists = NO;

    static sqlite3 *database = nil;
    sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt = NULL;

    if (sqlite3_open([kDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        DLog(@"BEGIN");

        sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

        NSString *sqlStatement = @"select countryexitcode from countries";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            columnExists = YES;
    }
    return columnExists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is use the core data migration.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html

Tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration